# HOW TO USE LONG DECIMAL NUMBERS IN PYTHON

Tags: python, physics

I am a novice in `python`. I am trying to use the `Sellmeier` Equation to calculate a refractive index. The coefficients of this equation are decimals to a large number of sig figs 
`( i.e B1 = 1.03961212, B2 =  0.231792344, C1 = 6.00069867×10−3 ... and so on)`
in the sellmeier formula there is a lot of fractions, multiplication and squaring of these numbers. I originally state them as floats. However such a process apparently cannot be done with `floats` like these.

What do i do?

Please need help!

Comment: WHY ARE WE TITLE-YELLING?

Answer (score -1):

You can use float64 Double precision float: sign bit, 11 bits exponent, 52 bits mantissa.
but for this you have to install 64 bit numpy and

```
import numpy as np
```

and you can use:
    np.float64